# Plc and Jetson nano connection problem tcp ip

Tags: tcp, plc

I am trying to connect to Siemens S7 1200 via TCP IP. I can ping it and it gets a response without any problems. When I run the same code on Windows, I can get the data. but when I run the following code on jetson nano, I get the following error:

> s.connect((HOST, PORT)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused

```
import socket

HOST = ‘192.168.0.1’
PORT = 2000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

s.connect((HOST, PORT))

s.sendall(b'Hello, server!')


while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break  

    try:
        decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print('Received', decoded_data)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:

        decoded_data = data.decode('ISO-8859-1')
        print(decoded_data)
print(‘connection closed.’)
```